# Typescript abstract class without implementation without errors

Tags: angular, class, typescript, abstract

Is it possible to have an abstract class with strongly typed public methods but without implementation of them? **I know it's an interface**, but I can't use interface for Dependency Injection as a token in Angular. I need a structure for my other classes to implement.
However, if I do something like this:

`abstract class AbstractService  {
     someMethod(): Observable<SomeType> {}
}`

Typescript will statically check it and error because it doesn't return a declared type.

I guess I can add some comments to the compiler code to prevent TS checking, but it seems to hacky.

Is there a way to prevent typescript this check and do it write? Big piece of my architecture is this service layer system for DI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark fields and methods that are not implemented as `abstract`

```
abstract class AbstractService {
    abstract someMethod(): Observable<SomeType>
}
```

This will also force implementing classes to actually implement the methods:

```
// Error: Non-abstract class 'Service' does not implement inherited abstract member 'someMethod' from class 'AbstractService'
class Service extends AbstractService{

}


 //ok, methods is implemented
class OkService extends AbstractService {
    someMethod() {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}
```

You can read more about abstract classes [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks :) And I use `implements`, but it doesn't matter

Comment: @ŁukaszOstrowski while either `implements` or `extends` will force you to implement all methods of the class, their semantics are bit different. If you use implements the derived classes will not really inherit the abstract class, so any code inside the constructor or any methods will not be available in the derived class. Also `instanceof  AbstractService` will return false for instances of such classes

Comment: True. I use abstract class only because Angular cant resolve interface.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract hello(name: string): Promise<string>
    public abstract goodbye(name: string): Promise<string>
}
```

If you need to test your new class but you don't have all the methods implemented yet.

```
class Human extends Base {
    public hello(name: string) {
       // your implementation
    }
    public goodbye(name: string) {
        return 'Not implemented yet' as unknown as Promise<string>;
    }
}
```